# How to embed a character string (stored in a variable) in quotation marks using R?

Tags: r, string, character, quotes

How to use escape characters to embed a character string, stored in a variable, in single quotation marks?

I already gave it some try-and-error-approaches, but failed.

To illustrate what I want to achieve here an example:

```
from:
"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"

to:
'"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"'
```

Thanks a lot in advance, ExploreR

```
proj4string(spatial_data)
[1] "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
# this is the character string i want to embed into quotation marks

input_crs <- paste(\'input_crs\')
Error: '\,' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""\,"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option, adding single quotes around the input using `paste`:

```
from <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
to <- paste0("'", from, "'")
```

Or, if you want your input to be surrounded by literal double quotes, then use:

```
to <- paste0("\"", from, "\"")
```

Or we could use `sub`:

```
to <- sub("^(.*)$", "'\\1'", from)
```

Comment: mh... unfortunately you suggestion `input_crs_tim <- paste0("'", input_crs, "'")` is not the same like `input_crs <- '"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"'` which can be proven by `identical(input_crs_tim, input_crs)` but thanks anyway for your help and engagement, @Tim Biegeleisen ! :)

Comment: I can't figure out what you want.  I updated my answer with an option for surrounding with double quotes.

Comment: oooops, thanks a lot, @Tim Biegeleisen i was just reading too slowly... :D

Answer (score 0):

You would still need to surround by quotation marks, but can use double quotes rather than single, so either of the following work.

```
> input_crs <- '\'input_crs\''
> input_crs
[1] "'input_crs'"

> input_crs_2 <- "input_crs'"
> input_crs_2
[1] "input_crs'"
```

You don't need to use `paste0()` for that because things aren't being combined. If you were using a variable that had stored something, you would use `paste0()`:

```
> input <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"
> paste0("'", input, "'")
[1] "'+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0'"
```

Info on quotes [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Quotes.html) says:

> Single and double quotes delimit character constants. They can be used
>   interchangeably but double quotes are preferred (and character
>   constants are printed using double quotes), so single quotes are
>   normally only used to delimit character constants containing double
>   quotes.
>
> Backslash is used to start an escape sequence inside character
>   constants. Escaping a character not in the following table is an
>   error.
>
> Single quotes need to be escaped by backslash in single-quoted
>   strings, and double quotes in double-quoted strings.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and engagement, Megan i really appreciate it! but it is exactly what i want to do; to use a variable which is holding a character string and embed it in quotation marks. see @Tim Biegeleisen solution above :)